# Nexus3 snapshots repository does not allow uploads?

Tags: maven

I have installed and configured Nexus3 Repository Manager OSS for my work. I have created two repositories one for snapshots and one for releases. When I click on the upload button on the web UI only the releases repository shows up. I have double and triple checked my configuration and everything seems to be as it should be. Any ideas?
Actually, I cannot deploy from maven either, I get an unauthorized error... The two must be related.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the fact that there is no UI interface to uploading to a snapshot directory is a feature, nothing wrong there. I was able to upload as admin with maven no problem. But I can't upload as myself except via the web UI. That is a separate question though